# how to write the definition for this method i am getting error

Tags: c++, function, class, header

thanks in advance 
i am trying to write the definition for the method

```
Customer* getMemberFromID(std::string);
```

this is the definition i wrote but i am getting some error saying [Error] 'Customer' in 'class Store' does not name a type

```
Store:: Customer* getMemberFromID(std::string id)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < members.size(); i++)
    {
        Customer* c = members.at(i);
        if(c->getAccountID() == id)
        {

            return c;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
Customer* Store::getMemberFromId(std::string const& id)
```

Hard to say with a full [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (which you should really provide), but I'm guess `getMemberFromId` is a member function of `Store`, but `Customer` is *not* a member of `Store`, and you just got confused by the naming rules.

Note I swapped `(std::string id)` for `(std::string const& id)` to avoid an extra copy of the string, when you didn't need it.

Then you could just use the standard algorithm [`find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find):

```
Customer* Store::getMemberFromId(std::string const& id)
{
    auto foundPos = std::find_if(members.begin(),
                                 members.end(),
                                 [&](Customer* c){ return c->getAccountId() == id; });
    return (foundPos==members.end())
                ? nullptr
                : *foundPos;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help i tried but i am now getting an error saying id not captured

Comment: i solved that error and now another error popped up saying`[Error] no matching function for call to 'find_if(std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >::iterator, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >::iterator, Store::getMemberFromID(std::string)::<lambda(Customer*)>)'`

Comment: @user1210000 Did you `#include <algorithm>`? (sorry, I should have made that explicit, I thought it would be clear from the link).

Comment: From your error, `members` is a `std::vector<std::string>`, but in your original example it is clearly some container of `Customer*`. Are you sure you are using the right container for the first 2 arguments of `find_if`?

Comment: i'll send the link to you with complete program
[Click here on link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41930615/error-request-for-member-str-in-c-which-is-of-non-class-type) that code has now many changes which you have mentioned

Answer (score 2):

Function definition rule,

```
<return type>  <class name> :: <function name><Arguments>
```

corrected here:

```
Customer* Store::getMemberFromID(std::string id)
{
// code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function prototype is wrong.

Change

```
Store:: Customer* getMemberFromID(std::string id)
```

to

```
Customer* store::getMemberFromID(std::string id)
```